# Login/register not working when website deployed to Heroku

Tags: express, heroku, mongoose, passport.js

I have an express app that has been working fine on localhost:3000, and the mongoDB cloud database is also successfully connected, but when I deployed to Heroku the login and register timed out.

I got error code=h12 which is a timeout error. I wanna know if there is anything I am missing, or if I should use a different login/register plugin. Currently using passportJS and Passport-Local-Mongoose.

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

const Chart = require('chart.js');
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

const password = process.env.PASSWORD;

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static('public'));


app.use(session({
  secret: "null",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

passport.use(User.createStrategy());
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.post('/register', (req, res)=>{
  User.register({username: req.body.username}, 
req.body.password, function(err, user){
    if (err){
      console.log(err);
      res.redirect('/register');
    } else {
    passport.authenticate('local')
    (req, res,function(){
    res.redirect('/home');
  });
}
```

});
});

Comment: I think you might've completely missed `app.listen(process.env.PORT||3000)`

Comment: If you have any environmental variables locally, you also need to add those variables in Heroku too. Go to your heroku control panel, go to settings, and then click on Reveal config vars. There, you add your Key value pairs

Comment: Alex thank you so much!!! It works now.
It was so obvious but I think I probably never would have figured it out.

Comment: @EricLeRoy I just posted my comment as an answer. If it helped you could you please accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any environmental variables locally, you also need to add those variables in Heroku too. Go to your heroku control panel, go to settings, and then click on Reveal config vars. There, you add your Key value pairs